# Microsoft To Do duplicate a task within list or a different list including task details

Tags: duplicate, to-do

I have a template list on Microsoft To do. I want to be able to copy a single task within this list into another task (duplicate) then move it to wherever I need it and rename. Currently I can duplicate the complete list and delete or add tasks manually but if I need a second instance of a single task or if I need that task to be copied into another existing list I have to manually copy the single task and its details then move it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer from user1705387](https://superuser.com/a/1728753/631105) was correct but poorly explained, so here it is:

To duplicate a task, you need to use the [To Do browser app](https://to-do.office.com/tasks), click on the task with the left mouse button, and pick "Copy task to...". For some reason, the apps don't allow it (tested on Android and Windows 10 - Windows Store App) on 17-07-2022.

In the following example, you can see that you can copy the task in the browser (first image), but in the Windows App (second image), you can't.

[image: Task options in the browser]
[image: Task options in the Windows App]

There is an [idea for this in the Microsoft To Do feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/22ce7d7a-df1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472). The Microsoft Feedback Team created it, so maybe this post will become outdated soon. If this is a problem for you, upvote the idea :)

Comment: This definitely gets me closer to it but, I rather have the function on the desktop app because that's what I use constantly for many reasons. I will keep using the app Instead of using the site which I tend to stay away from for other Microsoft software. If I ever need to bulk copy template task into new lists I will jump on the site one. As of today this feature is not accessible on the MS windows desktop app nor on the apple app.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i've figured out how to duplicate tasks in To Do is to create and configure the "template task" then select "repeat." I chose 'daily' then I completed the task which automatically created a duplicate. I created as many duplicates as I needed then removed the 'repeat' and 'due date' on each one after. Now I have a template List with Tasks. Hope that helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this in the browser version (for some crazy reason).
Here's a youtube video explaining it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwBgDF65IT4&ab_channel=MeeTime

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: All of the information necessary to answer the question must be in the body of your answer. It should not be necessary to follow a link to get the answer. The link may be left for attribution or further research only.